# MySQL not accepting executemany() INSERT, running Python from Excel (datanitro)

Tags: python, mysql, excel, python-2.7, datanitro

**I HAVE ADDED MY OWN ANSWER THAT WORKS BUT OPEN TO IMPROVEMENTS**

After seeing a project at [datanitro](https://datanitro.com/blog/2013/5/23/Excel_and_sql/). I took on getting a connection to MySQL (they use SQLite) and I was able to import a small test table into Excel from MySQL.

Inserting new updated data from the Excel sheet was this next task and so far I can get one row to work like so...

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx")
c = db.cursor()

c.execute("""INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, userid, fname, lname)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);""",
      (Cell(5,1).value,Cell(5,2).value,Cell(5,3).value,Cell(5,4).value,Cell(5,5).value,Cell(5,6).value,))

db.commit()
db.close()
```

...but attempts at multiple rows will fail. I suspect either issues while traversing rows in Excel. Here is what I have so far...

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="xxx.com", user="xxx", passwd="xxx", db="xxx")
c = db.cursor()

c.execute("select * from users")
usersss = c.fetchall()

updates = []

row = 2 # starting row

while True:
    data = tuple(CellRange((row,1),(row,6)).value)
    if data[0]:
        if data not in usersss: # new record
            updates.append(data)
        row += 1
    else: # end of table
        break

 c.executemany("""INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, userid, fname, lname) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", updates)

db.commit()
db.close()
```

...as of now, I don't get any errors, but my new line is not added (id 3). This is what my table looks like in Excel...

[image]

The database holds the same structure, minus id 3. There has to be a simpler way to traverse the rows and pull the unique content for INSERT, but after 6 hours trying different things (and 2 new Python books) I am going to ask for help.

If I run either...

```
print '[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, updates))
```

or

```
print updates
```

my result is

```
[]
```

So this is likely not passing any data to MySQL in the first place.

**LATEST UPDATE AND WORKING SCRIPT**

Not exactly what I want, but this has worked for me...

```
c = db.cursor()
row = 2
while Cell(row,1).value != None:
    c.execute("""INSERT IGNORE INTO users (id, username, password, userid, fname, lname)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);""",
      (CellRange((row,1),(row,6)).value))
    row = row + 1
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution that gets me an Insert on new and allows for UPDATE of those that are changed. Not exactly a Python selection based on a single query, but will do.

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx")
c = db.cursor()
row = 2
while Cell(row,1).value is not None:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, \
    userid, fname, lname) \
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) \
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE \
    id=VALUES(id), username=VALUES(username), password=VALUES(password), \
    userid=VALUES(userid), fname=VALUES(fname), lname=VALUES(lname);",
    (CellRange((row,1),(row,6)).value))

    row = row + 1

db.commit()   
db.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is your problem:

```
while True:
    if data[0]:
        ...
    else:
        break
```

Your first id is 0, so in the first iteration of the loop `data[0]` will be falsely and your loop will exit, without ever adding any data. What you probably ment is:

```
while True:
    if data[0] is not None:
        ...
    else:
        break
```

Comment: You might be thinking of another language (Null is not in Python). But if you check out the bottom of my post, I was able to do similar using "!= None" and actually changed that to "is not None" in my project. I will likely put a bit more time into improving still though as it is for large amounts of data and the one I posted creates multiple queries.

Comment: Yea, of yourse you're  right, i ment `None`. Happens when your respond to python questions while writing java code... :)